# Make a secondary menu fly out over the boundaries of a vertically fixed DIV menu

Tags: html, css

I really apologize for the complicated title but I have no clue how to rephrase it. It's not as easy as it might sound to some either. I have a fixed DIV menu and I need to be able to open sub-menus by hovering over some of the menu items while at the same time maintaining the animations and responsive design that I am building. It is also important for the secondary menu to stick to the edge of the fixed div and be aligned with the item that one is currently hovering on as illustrated in the screenshot attached.

Does anyone have any idea how this could be accomplished?

[Here](http://codepen.io/Arthurik/pen/vOBOZz) is the result that I have achieved thus far on [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Arthurik/pen/vOBOZz). I can't get the secondary menu to cross the boundary of the fixed div.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="layout">
<div id="menu">
<div class="rcade-menu">
  <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="menu-item">ITEM 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="menu-item">ITEM 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="menu-item">ITEM 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">SUB 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Sub 2</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Arthur

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: @K.B.M, I'm such a nincompoop. Here it is - http://oi59.tinypic.com/wtwpwp.jpg. Basically I need the secondary menu to stick to the edge of the main menu div from the outside at all times. I might be asking for too much. Thank you very very much for answering!

Answer (score 0):

ul li ul{

```
position:absolute;
display:none;
right:0;
left:0;
```

}

width and text alignment you can adjust as you like

Comment: Hi Pushpender. Thank you for the answer. I tried and it doesn't seem to work. This is the result that I am looking for  oi59.tinypic.com/wtwpwp.jpg  and I do realize that it might be impossible.

Comment: Hey Arthur, I know by now u must have fixed this, if not 
1. one way is by adding extra wrapper div refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582233/how-can-i-get-an-absolutely-positioned-div-to-extend-outside-its-relativley-posi 
2. you can use popovers.

and you can also add your answer how you solved it, might help someone else.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the answer Pushpender. It is never too late for an answer. Unfortunately or fortunately, I gave my money to a pro and had the whole website designed by him. The final version is so far away from where I initially started that the menu in question doesn't exist anymore. Thank you once again for taking the time. Papa bless.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jv6yvjmk/1/)**

CSS:

```
ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
ul li ul li {
    color:#fff;
    background:red;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    padding:4px 10px;

}
ul li ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;   
}
ul li ul li:hover {     
    color:#fff;
    background:#b00620;

}
```